# Vim Avoid "Hit the enter key or enter a command"

Tags: vim

I have the following configuration in my .vimrc file to switch between a .c File and it's corresponding .h File

```
function SwitchHeader()
    w
    if(&ft=='cpp')
        e %:r.c
    elseif(&ft=='c')
        e%:r.h
    endif
endfunction
```

When i enter `:call SwitchHeader()` into the vim command line
The message appears `Bestätigen sie die EINGABETASTE oder geben sie einen Befehl ein` which i would translate to `Hit the enter key or enter a command`

How can i avoid having to press enter every time i call the function, when i bind key i can use `<cr>` at the end of the line to insert an Enter, but how can do this in the function.

Comment: I copied your function to a file, `~/enter.vim`, created three files, `enter.cpp`, 'enter.c` and `enter.h`, and executed `vim -N -u NONE --cmd 'filetype on' -c 'so ~/enter.vim' enter.cpp`. Then executing `:call SwitchHeader()` switches between those files, but there is no "Hit Enter" message. So I don't see the problem. You might take a look at `:help hit-enter-prompt` and see if that provides a clue.

Comment: Prefix your `:write` and `:edit` commands with `:silent`.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know where to put the :silent, cut you explain that further or provide and example?

Comment: Looks like you already have a solution, but for future reference, :silent just prefixes normal :-commands, e.g.: `:silent :write`, `:silent :edit ...`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
execute ':edit ' . expand('%:r') . '.EXT'
```

(Note: replace `.EXT`  by whatever you want it to be in each branch)

Also: have a look at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31

Comment: Ok, this solution works, but strangly only if i substitute both edit command in the if block, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone having the same problem: i found this vim plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=31 which seems to have more options, like splitting the pane and so. I didn't try it, but you might give it a try.

Comment: "i found" is a bit ... strange. i posted it 1 hour ago :)

Comment: Ohh, sorry, your answer worked for me so i didn't follow the link and didn't realize that you posted the same link

Answer (score 0):

In 'quick-and-dirty' scripts, the solution is often to insert the literal character into the file.  In this case you would type control+v followed by the return key, to insert a character looks like an `^L` but you can tell it isn't caret-ell because the cursor moves across it as one character.

Characters entered into the file this way do not tend to survive copy-and-paste, and various other means of transmission, however, they *can* get the job done.  Sometimes it is even necessary to wrap them in a call to execute normal. For example:

```
execute 'normal (...commands that might generate enter prompt...)^L'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `:set cmdheight=2`

From `:help messages`

```
To reduce the number of hit-enter prompts:  
- Set 'cmdheight' to 2 or higher.
```